# Python IF unexpected behavior when using OR

Tags: python, if-statement

I don't understand why the code below enters the IF statement.

```
#Cisco XR

print('*Read Channel before')
print(read_channel_password)

print(f'\nHostname: {hostname}')
print(f'Hostname upper: {hostname.upper()}')

if f':{hostname}#' or f':{hostname.upper()}#' in read_channel_password:
    print('\n*Read Channel after')
    print(read_channel_password)
    
    print("\nWhy are you here?")
    break
```

Console:

```
*Read Channel before

--- JUNOS 9.5R3.7 built 2009-10-28 16:48:40 UTC
{master}
user01@ed-ra1>

Hostname: ed-ra1
Hostname upper: ED-RA1

*Read Channel after

--- JUNOS 9.5R3.7 built 2009-10-28 16:48:40 UTC
{master}
user01@ed-ra1>

Why are you here?
```

When I change the IF to IF-ELIF instead of OR. It works normally. Am I missing something here?

Comment: `in` is not distributed across `or`. You need to write `if x in variable or y in variable:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both sides of `or` need a conditional so instead of:

```
if f':{hostname}#' or f':{hostname.upper()}#' in read_channel_password:
```

You need:

```
if f':{hostname}#' in read_channel_password or f':{hostname.upper()}#' in read_channel_password:
```

Your current code will always return `True` as long as `f':{hostname}#'` is not empty since non-empty strings are truthy.

Comment: Exactly.  If you do `if f':{hostname}#'`, then you're just testing the boolean value of the string.  Strings are considered to be true when they're not empty.

Comment: Wow, basic stuff that I should know. Thank you guys.